# Series from highcharts not showing up

Tags: php, json, charts, highcharts

This is my first time using Highcharts and I'm struggling with a little problem that doesn't let me go further in my work.

I have a database in MySQL and I'm trying to show some infomation on a graph using Highcharts.

The problem is that even after several try, I'm still not being able to show my series and I can't see why.

Here's my code :

data.php

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql=<<<SQL
        SELECT DATE, Traf_BH_TCH_Erl, Trafic_HR_BH, Block_BH_TCH 
        FROM 182_d_all 
        WHERE BCF='TIMNAY'  
SQL;
$reponse = $bdd->query($sql);


$bln = array(); 
$rows = array();
$bln['name'] = 'Date';
$rows['name'] = 'Traf_BH_TCH_Erl';          

while($donnee=$reponse->fetch()){
    $bln['data'][] = $donnee['DATE'];
    $rows['data'][] = $donnee['Traf_BH_TCH_Erl']; 
    }
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt, $bln);
array_push($rslt, $rows);
print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$reponse->closeCursor(); 
?>
```

line.php

```
<?php
$cakeDescription = "Highcharts Pie Chart";
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $cakeDescription ?></title>
        <link href="webroot/css/cake.generic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Random title',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Random subtitle',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Date'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Traf_BH_TCH_Erl'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: 'Hz' 
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: []
                };
                $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //xAxis: {categories: []}
                    options.series[0] = json[1];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            }); 

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- <a class="link_header" href="/highcharts/">&lt;&lt; Back to index</a> -->
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that all the values of the series are equal to zero.
I don't understand why it's all blank instead of showing values?

Thank you for your answers!

**EDIT :**

The JSON looks something like :

> [{"name":"Date","data":["\n5/6/2015 00:00:00","\n17/6/2015 00:00:0","\n15/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n26/6/2015 00:00:0","\n18/6/2015 00:00:0","\n18/6/2015 00:00:0","\n16/6/2015 00:00:0","\n7/6/2015 00:00:00","\n9/6/2015 00:00:00","\n3/6/2015 00:00:00","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n9/6/2015 00:00:00","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n20/6/2015 00:00:0","\n7/6/2015 00:00:00","\n24/6/2015 00:00:0","\n9/6/2015 00:00:00","\n22/6/2015 00:00:0","\n26/6/2015 00:00:0","\n26/6/2015 00:00:0","\n17/6/2015 00:00:0","\n17/6/2015 00:00:0","\n16/6/2015 00:00:0","\n16/6/2015 00:00:0","\n24/6/2015 00:00:0","\n22/6/2015 00:00:0","\n24/6/2015 00:00:0","\n22/6/2015 00:00:0","\n3/6/2015 00:00:00","\n20/6/2015 00:00:0","\n20/6/2015 00:00:0","\n3/6/2015 00:00:00","\n7/6/2015 00:00:00","\n28/6/2015 00:00:0","\n25/6/2015 00:00:0","\n25/6/2015 00:00:0","\n25/6/2015 00:00:0","\n5/6/2015 00:00:00","\n5/6/2015 00:00:00","\n28/6/2015 00:00:0","\n28/6/2015 00:00:0","\n15/6/2015 00:00:0","\n15/6/2015 00:00:0","\n23/6/2015 00:00:0","\n21/6/2015 00:00:0","\n19/6/2015 00:00:0","\n19/6/2015 00:00:0","\n19/6/2015 00:00:0","\n30/6/2015 00:00:0","\n30/6/2015 00:00:0","\n28/5/2015 00:00:0","\n18/6/2015 00:00:0","\n1/7/2015 00:00:00","\n1/7/2015 00:00:00","\n1/7/2015 00:00:00","\n8/6/2015 00:00:00","\n8/6/2015 00:00:00","\n8/6/2015 00:00:00","\n4/6/2015 00:00:00","\n4/6/2015 00:00:00","\n4/6/2015 00:00:00","\n28/5/2015 00:00:0","\n28/5/2015 00:00:0","\n29/5/2015 00:00:0","\n29/5/2015 00:00:0","\n29/5/2015 00:00:0","\n31/5/2015 00:00:0","\n6/6/2015 00:00:00","\n6/6/2015 00:00:00","\n6/6/2015 00:00:00","\n30/5/2015 00:00:0","\n30/5/2015 00:00:0","\n21/6/2015 00:00:0","\n21/6/2015 00:00:0","\n10/6/2015 00:00:0","\n10/6/2015 00:00:0","\n10/6/2015 00:00:0","\n23/6/2015 00:00:0","\n23/6/2015 00:00:0","\n29/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n27/6/2015 00:00:0","\n29/6/2015 00:00:0","\n29/6/2015 00:00:0","\n27/6/2015 00:00:0","\n27/6/2015 00:00:0","\n30/5/2015 00:00:0","\n30/6/2015 00:00:0","\n1/6/2015 00:00:00","\n1/6/2015 00:00:00","\n1/6/2015 00:00:00","\n31/5/2015 00:00:0","\n31/5/2015 00:00:0","\n2/6/2015 00:00:00","\n2/6/2015 00:00:00","\n2/6/2015 00:00:00","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n11/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0","\n12/6/2015 00:00:0"]},{"name":"Traf_BH_TCH_Erl","data":["14,49","17,47","12,96","13,10","13,10","12,03","5,59","10,33","3,68","10,42","14,92","12,82","14,49","11,93","12,03","11,47","5,59","11,09","12,29","10,31","5,63","10,15","9,82","4,56","15,58","8,52","12,77","7,56","10,18","11,23","3,36","4,08","11,96","9,97","3,98","5,69","4,97","13,49","8,55","7,88","4,17","12,25","5,81","8,69","4,72","12,01","5,59","11,58","9,77","9,69","8,47","2,89","9,61","3,24","12,71","8,27","12,36","10,42","3,67","14,21","13,59","4,92","15,37","13,56","4,44","11,41","7,39","14,90","11,77","6,63","11,02","12,68","11,48","5,19","12,37","5,84","8,26","3,87","12,71","11,79","5,37","8,94","3,27","9,82","13,10","12,03","5,59","11,31","9,06","3,65","10,13","4,06","9,11","9,79","11,71","11,57","5,46","9,37","4,59","13,62","13,33","5,34","13,10","12,03","5,59","13,10","12,03","5,59","13,10","12,03","5,59","10,59","10,00","4,77","10,59","10,00","4,77"]}]

Comment: Check the data in the database

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did and the data is correct. When I look at data.php on my localhost I can see all the values in a format JSON

Comment: Could you paste your JSON here  ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Yes, sure I added it above.

Comment: The problem is that your values are strings, but should be numbers. So please parse each value for example by parseFloat()

Comment: Thank you @SebastianBochan now it works in fact!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here...

A few changes I did to get a functional example from your data:

- You must create a 'data' field inside 'series':

  ```
  series: [{
      data: []
  }]
  ```
- You must set the 'data' attribute from 'series[0]' and pass the data field from your JSON:

  ```
  options.series[0].data = text[1].data;
  ```
- You must use numbers as y coordinate data, so you should use dot as decimal separator and do not use quotes:

  ```
  {"name":"Traf_BH_TCH_Erl","data":[11.23,3.36,4.08,11.96,9.97]}
  ```
- You are not using X axis with date format properly, but you can search for that after you get your first Highcharts working. ;)

Functional example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vveogjts/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. If you still have problems feel free to let us now. If your problem was solved, you should consider accepting this answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).